# Trigger pl/sql insert data on table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

i'm new in pl/sql. I'm trying to create a trigger that insert datas in specific tables.
I have datas that arrives in real-time on my table EV_48h. To know on which table I have to insert the data i have to know it Ref_equip (Ref_equip is on an other table named C_Equip).
I've made quickly this littre merise to be more understandable:
[merise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I32Zz.jpg)

As I said  I have data that arrives on real-time on the table EV_48H and I have to put them automatically on the tables that are named 'EVV_'+Ref_equip.

So, here is my code. I don't have any error but it don't work. I know i missed of forget something but i don't know what.

```
TRIGGER "SIVO"."NEWtrigger3EV_48H"
BEFORE INSERT
ON SIVO.EV_48H
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

declare
clef_var number(4,0);
ref_equip varchar2(40);
V_Nom_table varchar2(1000) ;
V_nom_seq Varchar2(2000) ;
stmt varchar2(200);

begin
SELECT clef_var
INTO :New.Clef_Var
FROM sivo.c_variable
WHERE Ref_Var= :new.Ref_Var; 
  -- Conversion des formats Date-Heure en DateHeure oracle
  :New.EV_DATEAUTO := to_date(:New.EV_DATE || ' ' || :New.EV_HEURE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS');   
  stmt:='begin select clef_var into :New.Clef_Var From sivo.C_variable; end';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt using out clef_var; 

  IF clef_var is not null then

    stmt :='begin select Ref_equip into :New.Ref_Equip FROM sivo.C_Equip WHERE Ref_var= :New.Ref_Var; end';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Stmt USING OUT Ref_Equip;
    V_nom_table := 'EVV_'||Ref_Equip;
    stmt :='insert into' ||V_nom_table || '(:New.Clef_Var, :New.Ev_DateAuto, :New.Ev_Valeur )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt USING Ref_Equip; 

  ELSE
  INSERT INTO SIVO.EV_48H_VAR_INCONNUES (REF_VAR, EV_DATE, EV_HEURE, EV_VALEUR)
  VALUES ( :New.REF_VAR, :New.EV_DATE, :New.EV_HEURE, :New.EV_VALEUR);

  end if;
END;
```

If someone can help me or put me on the right way. I don't know if I give all informations so tell me if I missed something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your execute immediate you are missing the end of statement indicator colon after END
this should be

```
begin select clef_var into :New.Clef_Var From sivo.C_variable; end;
```

However there are other design choices that you should be aware of:

- using execute immediate is handy but if you don't have to use it you shouldn't. The work can be done by a cursor or even a simple select statement if only one value will come back.  In fact it appears you do the work twice. First you insert into the :new.clef_var then you do the same thing again with the execute immediate.  Try commenting out the execute immediate.
- by using execute immediate any errors are harder to track
- using a trigger means the real time data source cannot end the transaction until the trigger completes.  Why not run a scheduled job every minute to check for new data and process it?  This breaks the transaction into two parts: data entry and data processing
- is there any update of records that your process needs to capture?